# access iPhone simulator root and home directories

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, directory-structure, absolute-path

I need to find a path where iPhone simulator root `/` and home `~` directories lies. With `NSFileManager` I can print their contents, however I need to place some files there so that I could open them with my application in simulator.

My operating system is `OS X 10.9.4` on mac-mini.

Update:

Basically what I need to access simulators file system and not the sand-boxed location that is relative to an app, and this is because I need to test my app with absolute paths. For example if that would be an sd card or just some other known location.

To emphasize what I am asking for. With this code:

```
    NSFileManager* fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSArray* rootContent = [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:@"/" error:nil];
    NSLog (@"ROOT dir contains:");
    for (NSString* fileName in rootContent)
        NSLog (@"%@", fileName);
```

I get this output:

```
2014-07-18 11:08:02.893 appName[34509:60b] ROOT dir contains:
2014-07-18 11:08:02.893 appName[34509:60b] .DocumentRevisions-V100
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .file
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .fseventsd
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .hotfiles.btree
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .PKInstallSandboxManager
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .Spotlight-V100
2014-07-18 11:08:02.894 appName[34509:60b] .Trashes
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] .vol
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] Applications
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] bin
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] cores
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] dev
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] etc
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] home
2014-07-18 11:08:02.895 appName[34509:60b] Library
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] mach_kernel
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] net
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] Network
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] private
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] sbin
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] System
2014-07-18 11:08:02.896 appName[34509:60b] tmp
2014-07-18 11:08:02.897 appName[34509:60b] User Information
2014-07-18 11:08:02.897 appName[34509:60b] Users
2014-07-18 11:08:02.897 appName[34509:60b] usr
2014-07-18 11:08:02.897 appName[34509:60b] var
2014-07-18 11:08:02.897 appName[34509:60b] Volumes
```

So this is a root `/` directory content and I want to access it in my OS-X file system, if that is possible, well and if it is not possible it would be great to know if there is any other location which I could access with my application and file system with a known absolute path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to open the folder on your Mac, you can use a software named SimHolder.
If you want to access these folders in your iPhone Application on iOS simulator, you can't open any folder outside your iOS app's sandbox.

Comment: This is a useful program, thank you. However This is not what I am asking for.. I need to access absolute directories, and not relative to my application, I am able to access them, and this program does the same thing, just it is more convenient as I can see.

I am able to see what is on iOS simulator's root and home directories trough my application, however I can't find where those locations exist on my file system.

Basically what I need is some common directory that would be reachable through absolute path and would not necessarily be in the context of an app.

Comment: Could you please update your answer? You said that I can not access 'these' folders in my iPhone application. From the context it seems that you were saying that I can not access application's documents and other folders, but I actually can, it's all in /Users/<your user>/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1/Applications/<your application directory>/, just like others said. But it keeps me wondering if you meant that any directory outside the app can not be reached.. And that would be the right answer. If you would update it, I could accept it :).

Comment: But of course there are exceptions in this rule, it looks like applications can share their directories (or directory Documents :?) by providing access and giving absolute path to that directory, but only in read only access. However this one I haven't tried myself, just read about it, so you could correct me if I am wrong :).

Answer (score 1):

Another easy way is this:

Open up finder
From the finder menu bar (at the top) find the go option and select "Go to Folder"

Put your path - /Users/userName/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator - in the go to folder option.

The folder that you want opens up.

You can now pull it to your favorites in the left hand side of your finder.

Comment: if you not able to find the folder then type this in your terminal:-
chflags nohidden ~/Library/

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you use an app called simpholders: http://simpholders.com/

It will place an icon in your mac menu bar that will allow you to easily access the folders of any iOS app you run on your simulator.

Answer (score 0):

On my machine all the installed applications live in:

```
/Users/dom/Library/Application\ Support/iPhone\ Simulator/7.1/Applications/
```